# aframe not recognizing daydream-controls

Tags: aframe, daydream

I am trying to create a basic scene using daydream controls but the component doesn't seem to be working for me. I am using version 0.6.0.

Here is what my controls look like:

```
<a-camera position="-0.016155197760135586 1.6 3.256854190620799" daydream-controls="hand:right;model:true;armModel:true" wasd-controls look-controls mouse-cursor></a-camera>
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/daydream-controls.md), the daydream controls are separate entities, like hand entities:

 `<a-entity daydream-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
 <a-entity daydream-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>`

Please make sure You make it this way, and not by attaching the controls component to the camera.